# How can I deploy aws resources using external Jenkins and terraform. (I don`t like my Jenkins running in ec2 or in aws)

Tags: jenkins

How can I deploy aws resources using external jenkins and terraform. (I don`t like my jenkins running in ec2 or in aws) because it may terminate at any time and every time I have to build from ami or all steps that I do on first time. I mean to say save all settings and credentials etc. So, I looking for some solution to install it on my VM/virtual box and then run pipeline job there and build aws resources/ services using terraform.

Answer (score 0):

You can run terraform or jenkins from anywhere to create resources in AWS.
Jenkins is just an orchestrator tool which will use terraform to create resources.
We only need to change how terraform interact with your AWS environment.

if you are having terraform on one of the AWS EC2 you can utilize EC2 metadata to interact/authenticate with AWS.
now as you move towards your local system or VM you have to change the way how you authenticate with terraform.

you can use below code in terraform to authenticate with AWS

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

please refer terraform documentation for more authentication methods
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication-and-configuration